# Replace a string with single quotes using sed

Tags: bash, sed, replace

I am trying to use `sed` to replace a string in a large configuration file, but it needs to be done via a script due to automation requirements.

Currently this is my test file -

```
# The below line should get modified.
var HOSTED_VIEWER_ORIGINS = ['null', 'http://mozilla.github.io', 'https://mozilla.github.io'];
```

And this is my current script excerpt -

```
#/bin/bash
ORIGINSORIGINAL="var HOSTED_VIEWER_ORIGINS = ['null', 'http://mozilla.github.io', 'https://mozilla.github.io'];"

ORIGINS="var HOSTED_VIEWER_ORIGINS = ['https://s3-host1.lab.example.com', 'https://s3-host1.prod.example.com', 'null', 'http://mozilla.github.io', 'https://mozilla.github.io'];"

sed -i "s@${ORIGINSORIGINAL}@${ORIGINS}@g" /tmp/sedtest.txt
```

For some reason the string is not being matched by `sed` and the replacement is not happening. Is there something obvious I am missing or do I need to escape part of the `sed` command given the original string has single quotes contained within it.

Thanks!

Comment: Square brackets in the search string are metacharacters and must be carefully quoted. Since you are using variables in double quotes you will have to be ESPECIALLY careful, and likely backquote the backquotes...

Comment: @PaulHodges that was it - the square brackets when escaped (with a more general search) made this so easy. Thanks!

Comment: lol -- was posting an example and you beat me to it. ;)

Comment: @PaulHodges marked yours as correct since you nailed it - thanks again so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simplistic solution:

```
$: ORIGINSORIGINAL="var HOSTED_VIEWER_ORIGINS = .*" # no metas
$: ORIGINS="var HOSTED_VIEWER_ORIGINS = ['https://s3-host1.lab.example.com', 'https://s3-host1.prod.example.com', 'null', 'http://mozilla.github.io', 'https://mozilla.github.io'];"
$: sed "s@${ORIGINSORIGINAL}@${ORIGINS}@g" /tmp/sedtest.txt
var HOSTED_VIEWER_ORIGINS = ['https://s3-host1.lab.example.com', 'https://s3-host1.prod.example.com', 'null', 'http://mozilla.github.io', 'https://mozilla.github.io'];
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the single quoted strings were not the issue, but actually were the square brackets which weren't being escaped correctly.

Changing my script to this (escaping the brackets and having a more general search) worked like a charm.

```
#/bin/bash
ORIGINSORIGINAL="var HOSTED_VIEWER_ORIGINS = \[.*\];"

ORIGINS="var HOSTED_VIEWER_ORIGINS = ['https://s3-host1.lab.example.com', 'https://s3-host1.prod.example.com', 'null', 'http://mozilla.github.io', 'https://mozilla.github.io'];"

sed -i "s@${ORIGINSORIGINAL}@${ORIGINS}@g" /tmp/sedtest.txt
```